# Can QGIS alone can be used without installing grass?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

can QGIS alone can be used without installing grass? i want to use functions of grass and i am not  interested to create mapset and all. just with raster and vector files, i want to study  temporal data. will it be possible with qgis alone? what is the procedure.

Comment: You "want to use functions of grass" but you don't want to install GRASS? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: If you want to study temporal data, you may want to reconsider usage of GRASS GIS itself since GRASS GIS 7 has a temporal framework ([TGRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/temporalintro.html)) which will help you to manage and analyze spatio-temporal data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the OSGEO4W installer (on Windows) and click on the Full Install option, it will painlessly install GRASS. The functions of GRASS will then be available from the Processing Toolbox and you won't have to create mapsets, QGIS will take care of that for you.

Comment: The standalone installer includes GRASS too. It might be helpful to install into a folder without blanks, like `C:\QGISValmiera\` .